# PL/SQL function to view maximum salary

Tags: plsql, aggregate-functions, stored-functions

I have function that receives department name and an aggregation operation (average, maximum, minimum) and applies the operation on the salary of employees working on the given department and return the result

```
create or replace
function salaryData (p_depname varchar2, p_aggr_op varchar2)
return number
is
  v_aggrr_op varchar2(20);
  v_sal_max number;
  v_sal_min number;
  v_sal_avg number;
begin
  select max(e.salary), min(e.salary), avg(e.salary)
  into v_sal_max, v_sal_min, v_sal_avg
  from employee e join department d
  on e.deptno=d.deptno
  where d.deptname=p_depname;
  if p_aggr_op in ('max','MAX') then
    return v_sal_max;
  end if;

  if p_aggr_op in ('min','MIN') then
    return v_sal_min;
  end if;

  if p_aggr_op in ('avg','AVG') then
    return v_sal_avg;
  end if;
end salaryData;
/
```

when i use function call

```
select salaryData('FINANCE','max') as max_sal from employee;
```

i got the ouput like:

```
max_sal|
-------|
20000  |
20000  |
20000  |
20000  |
20000  |
-------
```

how can i show that this is the maximum salary of employeeid, employeename working in departmentname

Comment: It's not clear to us exactly what you're asking.  Would it be possible to provide some sample input data and the output you'd expect to see?

Comment: did you consider using a group by ? like select ..., e.name into ... from ... where ... group by e.name;

Comment: Yup, to do this by employee id then a) The values is the same as the ordinary salary ( as I assume employee is unique on employee id ) and b) you're going to have to do a similar query to that inside the function again. You might just as well dump the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select salaryData('FINANCE','max') as max_sal from dual;
```

Dual exists to allow you to run functions once in sql.

Answer (score 0):

All you are doing is selecting the maximum salary for the finance department for every employee. Do you perhaps need to pass the employee's department? E.g.,

```
select e.employeeid, e.employeename, salaryData(d.deptname,'max') as max_sal from employee e join department d on e.deptno=d.deptno;
```

Which would at least provide the maximum salary of the department each employee belongs to and not just finance.